# How to create, write and read file in app for save and change data?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm new and try to make authorization in app. For example: I singed up and my username and password save in file. When I try to login I just read file. If it has my username and login I can login. And when I logged in I can change data in file.
I tried some examples for java but it don't work and don't help me in kotlin. Who can show some code example?

LogPassReg.kt

```
package ru.agatech.mkprsm

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.BaseColumns
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_log_pass_reg.*
import xdroid.toaster.Toaster.toast
import java.io.File

class LogPassReg : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_pass_reg)

        next.setOnClickListener {
            if (createpassword.text.toString() == repeatpassword.text.toString()) {
                val i = Intent(this, Categories::class.java)
                    .putExtra("singup", 1)
                startActivity(i)
            } else toast("passwords are different")
        }
        back.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }
}
```

log_pass_reg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LogPassReg">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Далее"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/createlogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="376dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Введите логин"
        android:textColorHint="#FF5F5F5F"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.484"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/createpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Введите пароль"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="#FF5F5F5F"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createlogin" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/repeatpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Повторите пароль"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="#FF5F5F5F"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createpassword" />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="94dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="95dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Назад"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried:

```
val file:String = fileName.text.toString()  
val data:String = fileData.text.toString()  
val fileOutputStream:FileOutputStream  
try {  
    fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)  
    fileOutputStream.write(data.toByteArray())  
}catch (e: Exception){  
    e.printStackTrace()  
}
```

and

```
val sd_main = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/yourlocation")
var success = true
if (!sd_main.exists()) {
    success = sd_main.mkdir()
}
if (success) {
    val sd = File("filename.txt")
    if (!sd.exists()) {
        success = sd.mkdir()
    }
    if (success) {
        // directory exists or already created
        val dest = File(sd, file_name)
        try {
            // response is the data written to file
            PrintWriter(dest).use { out -> out.println(response) }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // handle the exception
        }
    } else {
        // directory creation is not successful
    }
}
```

And nothing help me.
Or I need to work with SQLite database? Thank you for all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, I think you should use Android's Shared Preference to save your small amount of data like login credentials which will be saved locally.
[Go through the Android Offical documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

[Example of using shared Prefernce](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm#:~:targetText=Android%20provides%20many%20ways%20of,form%20of%20key%2Cvalue%20pair.)

Comment: Do you know some tutorial for kotlin?

Comment: http://www.kotlincodes.com/kotlin/shared-preferences-with-kotlin/  go through both                              https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/SharedPreferences    I guess this will do. Thankyou.